# Navigate through usages in CLion's Hierarchy View and opening the Hierarchy View for fields and constructors

Tags: c++, linux, clion, jetbrains-ide

I'm having some troubles when using the hierarchy view (`ctrl` + `alt` + `H`) in CLion 2020.2.3 for a C++ project. I could not figure out the following two things, even after searching the web:

1. Navigating between different usages: In the hierarchy view for a method `X`, there is sometimes a method `Y` that calls `X` from multiple places within the same method. It shows this by having (3 usages), for example, next to the method `Y`. When clicking on method `Y`, I get to the first usage of `X`. How can I navigate to the next usage of `X` within method `Y` (the remaining 2 usages)? I intuitively double clicked on it but that does not work.
2. Opening the hierarchy view does not seem to work on constructors and fields. Why? When following a call chain in the hierarchy view, it stops to load once a constructor is opened. This is a little bit annoying. This worked perfectly fine in Eclipse, for example.

Coming from Eclipse (using `ctrl` + `alt` + `G`/`H`), this is a pain point as I used the hierarchy view a lot there. Going over the usages window shows me the direct usages but not the hierarchy. Can anybody help on these two points or provide some suitable alternatives? Thanks a lot!